# How to apply code sample inside a line using org mode

Tags: org-mode

In `org-mode` when I type following example code:

```
#+begin_src python
def main(*args):
    from brownie import network, project
#+end_src
```

it will be previewed as, equivalent for `Code Sample` in markdown:
[image]

---

Would it be possible to achieve this for a singe for word or line `LIKE_THIS` code sample inside of a line:

---

Test `Hello World Doo` Test.

On the other hand preview of org mode:
[image: ![enter image description here]

---

When I try following `LIKE_THIS`  in the org mode I see following in the preview:
[image]

---

I have tried following which did not work:

`#+begin_src python LIKE_THIS #+end_src`

which printed just a new line inside a code piece:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you refer to a 'preview', are you talking about exporting the file? If so, to what format: pdf, html, something else?

Comment: The markup for inline source code is `src_<language>{<body>}`, i.e., `src_python{LIKE_THIS}`

Comment: @Tyler Format could be pdf or ex: `README.org` file's view on the github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup for generic code in Org is either `=code=` or `~code~`. If you want to execute that code, then `src_python{print("Hello, world")}`, and you can `C-c C-c` on that line, and it will evaluate and print the results within that sentence. See more at https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-Code-Blocks.html

Comment: `~code~` was excatly what I was looking for