# How can I apply code sample inside [] brackets in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In the `markdown-mode` I am able to do following: [`one`, `two`, `three`, `four`]

But in `org-mode` when I do:

[~one~, ~two~, ~three~, ~four~] , it printed as it is instead of converting `~varaible~` into code format. How can I pretent this to keep code sample format?

Related: [How to apply code sample inside a line using org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/69021/18414)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the `~` from the square brackets.

```
[ ~one~, ~two~ ]
```

seems to apply the org-code face to `~one~` and `~two~`.

You can also use a Zero-width space instead of the space (use `C-x 8 RET 200b` to enter it).

Comment: Would space in between `[ ~` will be applied?

Comment: What do you mean by "applied?"

Comment: Like would it be viewed as [<space>`one`

Comment: Yes. See the update for a workaround.

Comment: in my emacs `200b` does not return/show have any character  :-(

Comment: The character is zero-width, so it's not shown, but it separates the `[` from the `~`.

Comment: ah its `00200B` :-)

Comment: zero width space seems like did not work in the github's preview :( Please see the example view https://github.com/ebloc/ebloc-broker/tree/test

Comment: Then it's a bug in how GitHub interprets org files :-)

Comment: Ah let me open an issue on Github :-D

Comment: @alper: Maybe try https://github.com/novoid/github-orgmode-tests (not sure what GitHub uses to render org files)

Comment: Ah they told me that: I believe GitHub uses org-ruby to render .org files as HTML and open an issue on https://github.com/bdewey/org-ruby/issues